# How to convert a plain text password to SHA-1

Tags: python

I am trying to allow users to update their password. Currently, when I store the updated password in the database, in looks like this.

I am allowing users to update their own password, how do I get the current hash to the django default `sha1` hash.

```
password = hashlib.sha1(password).hexdigest()
```

output

```
be86dd8176c748e5a5676f3c7c32eeafe62ed764
```

expected output

```
pbkdf2_sha256$30000$6nrsbWJ7QoNg$Clt2K2iaucZJnm5Bx+h+H/Q5Tc/v08BB7qp4dZpZ/p8=
```

Comment: Obligatory: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: Have you created a django app? or just plain python app? If django then my answer would satisfy your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

password = "Password in plain text"
hashed_pwd = make_password(password, salt=None, hasher='default')
user_obj.password = hashed_pwd
user_obj.save()
```

Django docs ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#manually-managing-a-user-s-password

Comment: @MaximeLorant Can I know what is OP?

Comment: Original Poster, the person who post the question in Stack Overflow context.